# how to use GROUP_CONCAT in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$assignment = assignment::find(Crypt::decrypt($id));
$assignment_details = $assignment->raw_plan()->groupBy('flag')->get();
```

I want to following result of this query in laravel

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS 'names' FROM `raw_plans` where `assignment_id` = 1 GROUP BY`flag`
```

Please suggest me how to use GROUP_CONCAT in laravel

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use relations as query builder to fetch the results as:

```
$assignment_details = $assignment->raw_plan()
                                ->select(DB::raw('group_concat(name) as names'))
                                ->where('assignment_id', 1)
                                ->groupBy('flag')
                                ->get();
```

**Update**

Use `table_name.*` in select to get all the fields.

```
$assignment_details = $assignment->raw_plan()
                                ->select('raw_plans.*', DB::raw('group_concat(name) as names'))
                                ->where('assignment_id', 1)
                                ->groupBy('flag')
                                ->get();
```

Comment: but it only shows $assignment['names']. Can't see Other fields.

Comment: Check the updated answer. It will show other fields also.

Answer (score 12):

Try with below code

```
$data = DB::table('raw_plans')
            ->select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '-') as `names`"))
            ->groupBy('flag')
           ->where('assignement_id',1)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Getting the following error: 
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\group_concat()

Comment: $assignment = assignment::find(Crypt::decrypt($id));
$assignment_details = $assignment->raw_plan()->groupBy('flag')->get();
I want to use GROUP_CONCAT in raw_plans.flag

Comment: Your `controller` code, not part of it. Use `pastie`/`pasetbin` or similar service

Answer (score 8):

shoieb is somewhat right, but you should give table name before accessing column names in `DB:raw()`

You should try this:

```
$data = DB::table('raw_plans')
            ->select(DB::raw("group_concat(raw_plans.name)"))
            ->groupBy('flag')
            ->where('assignement_id',1)
            ->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `table` name is only required if you are joining and there are multiple `tables` with same `column name` , I guess

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS 'names' FROM `raw_plans` where  `assignment_id` = 1 GROUP BY`flag`";

  $info = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```