# Consolidate/concatinate rows of data with laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm retreiving data from severel tables in the following way:

```
$data = Accommodation::join("hotels", "accommodations.hotel_id", "=", "hotels.id")
        ->join("room_types", "accommodations.room_type", "=", "room_types.id")
        ->join("country", "accommodations.country_id", "=", "country.id")
        ->join("accommodation_accreditation", "accommodations.id", "=", "accommodation_accreditation.accommodation_id")
        ->join("accreditation", 'accreditation.id', "=", "accommodation_accreditation.accreditation_id")
        ->select('hotels.name as Hotel' ,'room_types.type as Room', 'price_per_night as Price per Night', 'check_in as Check In', 'check_out as Check Out', 'nights as Nights', 'sub_total as Sub Total', 'country.name as Country', 'accreditation.full_name as Occupants')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

And I receive a row for each occupant in a room.

```
          Room           Price per Night    Check In    Check Out    Nights   Sub Total   Country       Occupants      
 ---------------------- ----------------- ------------ ------------ -------- ----------- --------- ------------------- 
  Twin/Double standart               160   2019-04-10   2019-04-15        5         800   UKR       Vlad Timochenko  
  Twin/Double standart               160   2019-04-10   2019-04-15        5         800   UKR       Selena Viachenko
```

I need to concatinate names of occupants and get them in one row like this:

```
          Room           Price per Night    Check In    Check Out    Nights   Sub Total   Country               Occupants               
 ---------------------- ----------------- ------------ ------------ -------- ----------- --------- ------------------------------------ 
  Twin/Double standart               160   2019-04-10   2019-04-15        5         800   UKR       Vlada Nikolchenko, Olena Diachenko
```

Here is my schema for the tables in question

[image]

Hope it's clear. Will be greatfull if you could help.

Comment: This doesn't require any Laravel specific features, you can use MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Why people are afraid of using Eloquent relationships? Is there any specific reason why you haven't go with it?

Comment: @Benjamin Truth is I'm not very comfortable with it and I had to finish with this faster so I decided to use something more familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I found the complete solution for my case from different places.

As sam sugested I used `GROUP_CONCAT`. And my code looked like:

```
$data = Accommodation::join("hotels", "accommodations.hotel_id", "=", "hotels.id")
        ->join("room_types", "accommodations.room_type", "=", "room_types.id")
        ->join("country", "accommodations.country_id", "=", "country.id")
        ->join("accommodation_accreditation", "accommodations.id", "=", "accommodation_accreditation.accommodation_id")
        ->join("accreditation", 'accreditation.id', "=", "accommodation_accreditation.accreditation_id")
        ->select('hotels.name as Hotel' ,'room_types.type as Room', 'price_per_night as Price per Night', 'check_in as Check In', 'check_out as Check Out', 'nights as Nights', 'sub_total as Sub Total', 'country.name as Country', DB:raw("GROUP_CONCAT('accreditation.full_name SEPRATOR ',') as `Occupants`"))
        ->groupBy('accommodation.id')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

The other thing I had to be cearful was using back quotes for the Occupants label otherwise the SEPARATOR was not working properly.

There are other similar threads so this is a duplicate.

[Group_concat - laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847738/group-concat-laravel-eloquent)
[how to use GROUP_CONCAT in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486296/how-to-use-group-concat-in-laravel/40488705)