# Laravel relationship combine column to comma separated string

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, concatenation

In my laravel application I have 3 tables called `customers`, `packages` and `customer_packages`. I need to show every `package` of each customer in a `comma separated` string.

For example:

```
# | Customer     | Package(s)
------------------------------
1 | Customer - 1 | 123, 456, 789, ...  
2 | Customer - 2 | 456, 789, ...
```

Relationships:

```
customers -> hasMany -> customer_packages -> hasOne -> packages
```

Customer.php

```php
public function customerPackage()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CustomerPackage::class);
}

public function index() 
{
    return self::select([
        'id',
        ...
    ])->with([
        'customerPackage:id,customer_id,package_id,package_amount',
        'customerPackage.package:id,title',
    ])
    ->where("status", \Common::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    ->get();
}
```

CustomerPackage.php

```php
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
}

public function package()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Package::class);
}
```

Everything is working fine. However, to get the desired (comma separated) output I have to run the loop on packages and generate the output.

Something like this:

```php
@foreach($customers as $customer)
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            @foreach($customer->customerPackage as $package)
                @php
                    $array[] = $package->package->title;
                @endphp
            @endforeach

            {{ @implode(', ', $array) }}
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I hope I explained it clearly..

Comment: Depending upon your DB version, you might be able to `GROUP_CONCAT` the package titles. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40488705/7644018) ... and the other related answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can join your table then use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) to get such result:

```
 return self::leftJoin('customer_packages','customer_packages.customer_id','customers.id')
        ->leftJoin('packages','packages.id','customer_packages.package_id')
            ->selectRaw("customers.id ,customers.name,GROUP_CONCAT(packages.id SEPARATOR ',') packages")
            ->groupBy(['customers.id','customers.name'])->get();
```